# How to fix Deploy Error: Non-Zero Exit Code - Deploying in Digital Ocean

Tags: reactjs, digital-ocean

I start transitioning my react js project from aws to digital ocean hosting, and right now I experience some untraceable errors. The build logs completely success and Deploy logs has and error:

```
[2021-12-30 09:49:07] yarn run v1.22.17  
[2021-12-30 09:49:07] $ react-scripts start  
[2021-12-30 09:49:12] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://xxxxxxxx/  
[2021-12-30 09:49:12] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from   
[2021-12-30 09:49:12] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /workspace/public  
[2021-12-30 09:49:12] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /  
[2021-12-30 09:49:12] Starting the development server...  
[2021-12-30 09:49:12]   
[2021-12-30 09:49:12] Done in 4.97s.  
[2021-12-30 09:48:55] yarn run v1.22.17  
[2021-12-30 09:48:55] $ react-scripts start  
[2021-12-30 09:48:59] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://xxxxxxxx/  
[2021-12-30 09:48:59] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from   
[2021-12-30 09:48:59] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /workspace/public  
[2021-12-30 09:48:59] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /  
[2021-12-30 09:48:59] Starting the development server...  
[2021-12-30 09:48:59]   
[2021-12-30 09:48:59] Done in 4.20s.  
[]
```

Hope someone experience this error, help for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: that is the error logs given.

Comment: Log says the site starts in ~4 sec. Am I missing something?